# How to update bootstrap year calendar with Data from jqueryAJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar

I'm using this bootstrap year calendar:
http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Documentation/Options

I want to mark dateranges in red in which the respective workstation is already occupied according to the schedule. 
I'm using the following AJAX:

```js
function createCalendar(){
  $.post('../include/SitzplatzDetails/retrieveCalendarData.php', {
      arbeitsplatzID : 147
  }).then((calendarData) => {
    //calendarData = JSON.parse(calendarData);
    console.log("data from retrieveCalendarData.php is ", calendarData)
    //let calendarArray = [calendarData]
    //console.log("calendarArray is ", calendarArray)
    $('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource([calendarData])//TODO: This worked, make it with variable! ([{id: "865",name: "Andreas Lang",startDate: new Date('2018-12-23'),endDate: new Date('2018-12-30'),"color": "#FF0000",}])

  })
}
```

The funny thing is that it doesn't work, even though the data coming from the backend looks like above (see last two lines of comment). The data coming from the backend is a mere string, resembling exactly the structure of

```js
{id: "865",name: "Andreas Lang",startDate: new Date('2018-12-23'),endDate: new Date('2018-12-30'),"color": "#FF0000",}
```

When I put this string manually into the parameter of the setDataSource(), then it works. And for whatever reason, when this very string comes inside the variable from the AJAX, it doesnt work anymore :/

I also already tried putting the string into a JS array (see the commented code in the AJAX) but it didnt help. I also tried removing the arraybrackets "[]" around the string-variable "calendarData", but it didnt help. I'm out of ideas...^^

Comment: How are your date values actually formatted in the json response? Any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: The date values I inputted directly worked, and they have the same format as the dates coming from the database. No errors thrown in the browser console.

Comment: Javascript code and a string with code inside are two different things. You need to format your php script response so that it can be parsed to get the data, for example with JSON. But you won't be able to pass date objects construction `new Date('2018-12-23')` in your JSON, it won't work. You need to pass the value `'2018-12-23'` and build your date objects after the parsing.

Comment: OK but `new Date('2018-12-23')` can't be a string in json

Comment: okay, but the thing is, this kind of worked before. I separated backend from frontend, and in the process needed this AJAX above. However, the backendoperation is basically still the same as before, and it worked before. It was a "datasource : <?php //lots of code ?> construct, and the string Im echoing into the AJAX response now was the exact same. Or does the AJAX do something with the string? Like adding any slashes or the like, which in the end would change the new result compared to the former approach?

Comment: You cannot just copy and paste things anywhere and expect it to work every time, you need to understand a bit what's happening. By placing a `<?php //lots of code ?>` in your page, you dynamically build the Javascript code that will be sent to your client's browser. When you get data with a post request, you get data, not code, you cannot just "run" the result (not without causing a lot of security issues, at least). These are 2 different things happening here.

Comment: Ah thanks!
Okay, so if I manage to coax the data into the correct format (JSON?) I can insert it into the bootstrap calendars "datasource" property, correct? Is JSON format compatible with the bootstrap calendar, or do I need something else?